# Redis GET function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm building a very simple client/server app using node.js and redis for the first time. After successfully firing up my redis client and my http server, I'm trying to do a simple SET/GET with my redis client.

I first do:

```
client.set('apple', 10, redis.print);
```

which returns a `Reply:Ok`.

Immediately after, I execute:

```
client.get('apple', function(err, reply) {
    count = parseInt(reply);
    return count;
});
```

Strangely, upon printing out `count`, I get `undefined`. But, if I use `redis.print`, such as:

```
client.get('apple', redis.print);
```

A `Reply: 10` is returned in the console. `10` also shows up if I do a `console.log(count)`.

I thought maybe I was misusing the set functions in the module, but after referring to these both, I am unsure of what's causing my errors:

[node_redis - github readme](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)

[redis.io API - GET](http://redis.io/commands/GET)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> upon printing out count, I get undefined.

```
client.get('apple', function(err, reply) {
    count = parseInt(reply);
    return count;
});

console.log(count); // is this where you get undefined?
                    // count at this point is, in fact, undefined,
                    // because it's set in a callback which was not yet fired.
```

I don't program in node.js, so I'm not sure about benefits of *returning* count from the callback. Where would it return it to? Isn't it supposed to be something like this?

```
client.get('apple', function(err, reply) {
    count = parseInt(reply);
    // do something with the count here. Print it or whatever.
});
```

Or you could trap it in a closure, but then you'll need to somehow wait for callback to return and set the variable. How it can be done - I have no idea.

```
var count = null;
client.get('apple', function(err, reply) {
    count = parseInt(reply);
});

// TODO: wait for callback
console.log(count);
```

Comment: With node.js, you do not wait for callback completion. Typically the function should have a callback as a parameter, and this callback must be called with count as a parameter (instead of the pointless "return count"). This is CPS (continuation passing style).

Answer (score -1):

This is asynchonous, meaning the rest of the code is executed while waiting for the callback.

if you want to check if your set worked just print it :

> client.get('apple', function(err, reply) {
>
> console.log(reply);
>
> });